# Joomla create a confirmation button that send email to administrator

Tags: joomla

i have a big problem. I have to create a button that is taking the name and email of registred users and sending automatic email to the admin for confirmation.

Comment: Can you show us some code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla already has a feature so that admins must approve the registration of a user. Have a look here at the Joomla documentation:

https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_user%27s_registration_approval_by_admins

If you need a little more functionality, you may want to consider a 3rd party extension such as [Admin Approval](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/admin-approval)

Hope this helps